Rendering Issue with Conditional Slots in LitElement Component
I’m working on a LitElement component and encountering issues with rendering certain elements conditionally inside a card. Here’s a brief overview of the problem:
Context:
I have a LitElement component that displays a list of specialists. Each specialist card has various fields like name, position, email, LinkedIn URL, etc., which should be rendered conditionally based on the data provided.
Data Example:
Here is a sample data object for a specialist:
{
  "id": "57876228552",
  "link": "/nieuws/consultant",
  "quote": "\"lorem ipsum dolor\"",
  "name": "john doe",
  "position": "Developer",
  "emailText": "test@mail.com",
  "linkedinUrl": "https://www.linkedin.com/in/test/",
  "phoneNumber": "0612345678",
  "linkText": "Lees haar verhaal",
  "image": "test.com/img.jpg",
  "secondImage": "test.com/img2.jpg",
  "department": "Development",
  "function": "Developer"
}

Render code:
  render() {
    return html$3(_t || (_t = _`<section @pagechange="${0}" @filterdropdownchange="${0}"
               class="m-listing-specialists ${0} ${0} ${0}">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="filters">
              ${0}
            </div>
          <div class="list">
            <wcl-grid-row>
            ${0}
            </wcl-grid-row>
          </div>
          <div class="pagination">
            ${0}
          </div>
      </section>`), this.onPageChangeEvent, this.onFilterSelected, this.variant, this.spaceTop ? 'module_top-padding-' + this.spaceTop : '', this.spaceBottom ? 'module_bottom-padding-' + this.spaceBottom : '', this.filters && this.filters.length > 0 ? html$3(_t2 || (_t2 = _`
                ${0}
              `), this.filters.map((filter, index) => html$3(_t3 || (_t3 = _`
                  <div class="filter-column">
                    <wcl-stratech-dropdown-filter variant="secondary" title="${0}" label="${0}">
                      <wcl-stratech-dropdown-filter-option
                        title="${0}"
                        key="${0}"
                        value="">
                      </wcl-stratech-dropdown-filter-option>

                      ${0}
                    </wcl-stratech-dropdown-filter>
                  </div>
                `), filter.key, filter.title, this.dropdownPlaceholder, filter.key, filter.values.map((value, index) => html$3(_t4 || (_t4 = _`
                        <wcl-stratech-dropdown-filter-option
                          title="${0}"
                          key="${0}"
                          value="${0}">
                        </wcl-stratech-dropdown-filter-option>
                      `), value.name, filter.key, encodeURIComponent(value.name)))))) : html$3(_t5 || (_t5 = _`
              <div class="loader" slot="filters">
                <div class="lds-ellipsis">
                  <div></div>
                  <div></div>
                  <div></div>
                  <div></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            `)), this.listingSpecialists && this.listingSpecialists.length > 0 ? html$3(_t6 || (_t6 = _`
              ${0}
            `), this.listingSpecialists.map((item, valueIndex) => html$3(_t7 || (_t7 = _`
                <wcl-grid-column sm="6" md="4" class="card">
                 <wcl-stratech-specialist-card>
                  <wcl-media slot="media" type="cover" height="509px" src="${0}" alt="Placeholder"></wcl-media>
                   ${0}
                  ${0}
                  ${0}
                  ${0}
                   ${0}
                   ${0}
                  ${0}
                   ${0}

                </wcl-stratech-specialist-card>
                </wcl-grid-column>
                </wcl-grid-column>
              `), item.image, item.secondImage ? html$3(_t8 || (_t8 = _`<wcl-media slot="second-media" type="cover" height="509px" src="${0}" alt="Placeholder"></wcl-media>`), item.secondImage) : '', item.name ? html$3(_t9 || (_t9 = _`<p slot="name">${0}</p>`), item.name) : '', item.position ? html$3(_t10 || (_t10 = _`<p slot="position">${0}</p>`), item.position) : '', item.emailText ? html$3(_t11 || (_t11 = _`<wcl-icon-container slot="mail"
                                                              href="mailto:${0}"
                                                              background-color="#82C4FE"
                                                              border-radius="50%"
                                                              width="46px"
                                                              height="46px">
                    <wcl-stratech-icon slot="icon" icon="email" color="#fff" size="20"></wcl-stratech-icon>

                  </wcl-icon-container>`), item.emailText) : ``, item.linkedinUrl ? html$3(_t12 || (_t12 = _`<wcl-icon-container slot="linkedin"
                                                                 href="${0}"
                                                                target="_blank"
                                                                 background-color="#82C4FE"
                                                                 border-radius="50%"
                                                                 width="46px"
                                                                 height="46px">
                     <wcl-icon slot="icon" icon="linkedin" size="20px" color="#fff"></wcl-icon>

                   </wcl-icon-container>`), item.linkedinUrl) : '', item.phoneNumber ? html$3(_t13 || (_t13 = _`<wcl-icon-container slot="linkedin"
                                                                 href="tel:${0}"
                                                                 target="_blank"
                                                                 background-color="#82C4FE"
                                                                 border-radius="50%"
                                                                 width="46px"
                                                                 height="46px">
                     <wcl-icon slot="icon" icon="phone" size="20px" color="#fff"></wcl-icon>

                  </wcl-icon-container>`), item.phoneNumber) : ``, item.meetingUrl ? html$3(_t14 || (_t14 = _`<wcl-icon-container slot="meeting"
                                                                 href="${0}"
                                                                 background-color="#82C4FE"
                                                                 border-radius="50%"
                                                                 width="46px"
                                                                 height="46px">
                     <wcl-icon slot="icon" icon="Calendar" size="20px" color="#fff"></wcl-icon>

                     
                   </wcl-icon-container>`), item.meetingUrl) : '', item.quote ? html$3(_t15 || (_t15 = _`<p slot="quote">${0}</p>`), item.quote) : '', item.link && item.linkText ? html$3(_t16 || (_t16 = _`<wcl-stratech-link-icon slot="action" href="${0}" icon="arrow-right" icon-color="#82C4FE" icon-color-hover="#82C4FE" icon-size="20" icon-position="right">
                     ${0}
                   </wcl-stratech-link-icon>`), item.link, item.linkText) : html$3(_t17 || (_t17 = _``))))) : html$3(_t17 || (_t17 = _``)), this.listingSpecialists && this.listingSpecialists.length > 0 && this.totalPages > 1 ? html$3(_t18 || (_t18 = _`
              <wcl-stratech-pagination variant="secondary" space-top="xs" space-bottom="0" page="${0}" position="center"
                                   total-pages="${0}"
                                   last-page="${0}"></wcl-stratech-pagination>
            `), this.currentPage, this.totalPages, this.totalPages) : html$3(_t19 || (_t19 = _``)));
  }

If I remove the phone meeting slot="meeting" the code will work so if I add data it doesn't render it so is the issue in the render function or somewhere else?

I don't really know How i found it haha but there was an issue with the variables I set them all again and now it works.
